# JavaCC beginning of line

Tags: regex, javacc

Does JavaCC supports begging of line regex like '^' ?

I have a Token like this

```
TOKEN: { < ENTRYTK : "DATA"(" ")* > }
```

Would like it to match only the following regex

```
^"DATA"[ ]*
```

I have tried the following which neither works

```
TOKEN: { < ENTRYTK : "^DATA"(" ")* > }
TOKEN: { < ENTRYTK : ^"DATA"(" ")* > }
```

Comment: Did you get any error message or exceptions?

Comment: TOKEN: { < ENTRYTK : "^DATA"(" ")* > } matchs exact string '^DATA'
TOKEN: { < ENTRYTK : ^"DATA"(" ")* > } gives compiler error
org.javacc.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "^" "^ ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't.  Use lexical states to ensure that the production is only in play at the start of a newline.  Since every file starts with a newline, the default state will be the one for the start of a newline.